# How can I subset a dataframe based on ID letters?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have this df

```
df = data.frame(x = c('1E','2E','1F','2F'), y =1:4 )
```

and I wish to subset it into 2 dataframes based on the letters E and F

the resulted dataframes are as follows

```
   x y
1 1E 1
2 2E 2
```

```
   x y
1 1F 3
2 2F 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` with `gsub`. In the second argument, you can use whatever function that will make it so that you extract the letters of `df$x`:

```
split(df, gsub("\\d", "", df$x))
```

Use `list2env` if you want to subsequently convert the list into separate dataframes in your environment.

```
list2env(split(df, gsub("\\d", "", df$x)), .GlobalEnv)
```